# select2 multiple values store in database

Tags: mysql, database, yii, jquery-select2

I have successfully made a searchable drop down list,in which whenever I type something, data from database appears in drop down list, now I want to store these multiple values which are selected, in the database.

My code in controller

```
$temp = $model->package_item = $_POST['package_item'];   
foreach($temp as $t) 
{
    $model->package_item=$t;                      
}
```

`Package_item` is the field in which searchable dropdown list is applied, and I am selecting multiple values, now how can I save these values in the database, so that I will have a single id, but against this id, `package_item` will have multiple values and the rest of the attributes will be repeated. Just like below.

```
     id------package_item------package_description------package_name
     1--------cake------------ very cheap-------------get one buy one free
     1---------candles---------- very cheap-------------get one buy one free
     1----------fireworks--------very cheap-------------get one buy one free
```

I am using `select2` extension and here is the code for that in view file

```
  $this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2', array(
      'name' => 'package_item',
      'data' => CHtml::listData(Package::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'package_item'), //the whole available list
      'htmlOptions' => array(
           'placeholder' => ' search packge item?',
           //'options' => $options, //the selected values
           'multiple' => 'multiple',
           'style'=>'width:530px',
       ),
  ));
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

My first answer was terribly misleading, so I deleted it and here and giving it another try.

You need to plan out your database tables. I'm making a suggestion here:

Table **Items**

```
itemId[PK]|       name     | price |...|
     1    |       cake     | 5.00
     2    |      candles   | 2.00
     3    |     fireworks  | 10.00
     4    | expensiveStuff | 50.00
```

Table **Packages**

```
packageId[PK] |     name     |     description      | price |
     1        | full package |    super cheap       | 12.00
     2        | epic package | best value for money | 55.00
```

Table **PackagesItems**

```
packageId[PK][FK]|itemId[PK][FK]|amount
1 | 1 | 1
1 | 2 | 1
1 | 3 | 1
2 | 1 | 2
2 | 2 | 2
2 | 3 | 3
2 | 4 | 1
```

You would then query your packages like this:
`SELECT itemId FROM PackagesItems WHERE packageId = 1` for example

The keyword of this answer is `COMPOSITE PRIMARY KEY`, which you can see in the third table: there are two primary keys, which are also foreign keys that lead to the other tables.

With `SQL JOINS`, you could retrieve the information from the other two tables.
If you need more information, please narrow down the scope of your question. What exactly do you want to know?